# linux distro with generic hard drive naming

Tags: hard-disk, distributions

I manily use SUSE Linux, however it stores all device configuration and paths by ID (example: WD55844-Gh384) - which is a problem if I want to clone a disk then, replace it with a different disk. For example, say a Western Digital (WD) 250GB to Seagate 2TB disk.

Do all Linux distro's do this or is there one that only uses `/dev/sda` or `/dev/hd0` type naming that would be more flexible?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch those entries in `/etc/fstab`. So if they're using `UUID=XXXX` just change the label to `/dev/sda1`, or whatever it happens to be.

#### Example

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
UUID=XXX-XXX-XXX /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
```

Using the `blkid` command you can identify that this UUID is associated to this device handle:

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="XXX-XXX-XXX" TYPE="ext4"
```

So change the entry in `/etc/fstab` to this:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
/dev/sda1 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many path variations available to identify disks in Linux. You should look under `/dev/disk/` to see the various naming schemes: `by-id`, `by-label`, `by-partlabel` (GPT systems only), `by-partuuid` (GPT systems only), `by-path`, `by-uuid`.

Those will typically be symlinks to whatever `/dev/*` devices, and are likely to remain more consistent than the your hard drive remaining `/dev/sda`. I have a few systems where having a USB stick present on boot (but not booting from it) will cause my hard drive to shift down to `/dev/sdb`.

The `UUID` string in your `/etc/fstab` is actually unique to the partition, and if you clone the disk with dd, that UUID will remain the same unless you explicitly change it with `e2tune -U random`.